# NoClassDefFoundError with jetty-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jetty

I am getting a:

he Cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Msg:net/spy/memcached/MemcachedClient

When executing jetty:run -e in eclipse. Why isn't this dependency being added into the classpath?

Comment: The class containing the import is called with reflection. Is there a way to explicitly tell jetty/jetty-maven-plugin to include dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency had a provided scope. Change this.

Answer (score 2):

Which classpath do you expect it to be added to? If something in your project is trying to load it, ensure you have a project dependency that has that class in it. It looks like [it comes from ServiceMix](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spymemcached%22). If you've added something to Jetty itself to make it require that class, then [add the dependency to the jetty plugin](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing a runtime dependency. I searched Maven Central for the missing class

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient%22

Try adding the following to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spymemcached</artifactId>
    <version>2.5_2</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The class comes from spymemcached and I have of course added the dependencies. I am now trying to run the jetty-maven-plugin with the run-exploded goal and war packaging. The war is packaged properly with the dependencies but this error still happens. I think that the jetty-maven-plugin is failing or jetty is failing. Jetty is also warning the unresolved ignoring web.xml message.